# Meaning of phrase "joint-byline"

Tags: phrases, ambiguity

What does the phrase **joint-byline** mean for a multi-author article? Does it mean

*(1) All authors work under the name of a leader whose name appears as the single name in the byline*

or does it mean

*(2) All authors' names all appear in the byline*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is #2.  See, for example, [here](http://www.poynter.org/2010/new-ideas-on-the-old-joint-byline-question/110762/) and at [the Financial Times](http://www.ft.com/cms/s/2/91e2eeb8-ace3-11de-91dc-00144feabdc0.html?ft_site=falcon&desktop=true#axzz4NQG7ZDyP) at the [The Guardian](https://twitter.com/jameschappers/status/725434509592793088) newspaper.

Option #1 is pretty much never the case. Either the "leader" would claim full authorship (which would not be a "joint byline") while acknowledging the secondary assistance of contribution of others in some specific respect, or there would be a "corporate" author such as "the ATLAS Collaboration" or "the Editorial board" that doesn't mention the leader's name or anyone else's, or the byline would be anonymous such as "Staff Reporters".